# Visual FOXPRO9 onfocus commandbutton

Tags: foxpro, commandbutton

I have problem with command buttons in visual foxpro, the problem is when I point my focus with keyboard on button it gets some borders, similar to orders you get on windows icons.

How can I turn off those borders, I tried all options but cant figure it out. I'll post pictures with my code and how it looks like.

This is how it looks like

[image: this is how it looks like]

and this is the code.

[image: and this is the code]

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen the behavior you want is in the [ssDemos](https://github.com/VFPX/ssClasses). 
If you use only the click() event of the button - I can suggest you to use a picture instead of a button. 
 
But if you use more events - have a look on the buttonparts class - maybe implementing something simpler - an image, a button to overtake the focus, label, etc. could do a nice job. 
Good luck! PS I'm not an FoxPro expert, big chances are I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for advice, im trying to do it with images now, will figure something since i had a label that is changed depending on which button is on focus, its like explanation of focused button so dont know if ill be able to do it somehow with using imahes

Comment: Yes, this is why when you need more events of the button and you want to use images you need to have a button to to take the focus. This guy there has it smart with the focus taker. But not really easy to implement, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SpecialEffect = 1
BorderWidth = 0
```

Tamar

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this kind of problem by creating a new object with two shape(one for main, other for shadow), one label and one commandbutton(for keypress event).
You can download the class from
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnBsIoWEbiBXi3OPpfzPENcC3fOf